# Looking for dynamically creating and placing a picture box

Tags: vb.net, winforms, picturebox

I'm trying to place red crosses when the user double click on the screen.
So I have a picture box that extract X and Y position when we double click on it. (with a GetX() & GetY()) function.

I'm trying to dynamically create a picture box and fill it with my "cross.png" file.
Here's what I've tried so far :

```
Dim pb As New PictureBox
        pb.Width = 100 'or whatever
        pb.Height = 200
        pb.Top = 50 'or whatever
        pb.Left = 50
        pb.ImageLocation = "C:\Users\Over_\Desktop\proto_mini_project_-_face_recognition (1)\proto mini project - face recognition\proto mini project - face recognition\cross.png"
        Me.Controls.Add(pb)
```

I've found this solutions on StackOverflow but I don't really understand how to use it, or maybe I'm missing something. 
Alose I execute this part of the code in :

```
    Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles faceImage.DoubleClick
```

If anyone got an idea/solution I would gladly take it.
Kind regards,
Mehdi.

Comment: Can you give some more information please, like what exactly isn't working. Any errors?

Comment: Yes, so I don’t get any specific error message this is just that I don’t have any image that are displayed. I’ve tried with a button but still it doesn’t looks like something is happening even when I press the button multiple times

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution to my problem.
The new picture box wasn't in foreground, so i've added the following line : 
`pb.BringToFront()`